# How do I combine monads in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, monad-transformers

Particularly, I need to be able to combine the CGI monad with the IO monad, but an example of how to combine the IO monad with the Maybe monad might be even better...

Comment: interesting read: [Monad_transformers](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Typeclassopedia#Monad_transformers)

Answer (score 22):

I assume you want to use the Maybe monad for early termination (like `break` or `return` in C).

In that case you should use `MaybeT` from the MaybeT package (`cabal install MaybeT`).

```
main = do
  runMaybeT . forever $ do
    liftIO $ putStrLn "I won't stop until you type pretty please"
    line <- liftIO getLine
    when ("pretty please" == line) mzero
  return ()
```

MaybeT is a monad transformer version of the maybe monad.

Monad transformers "add functionality" to other monads.

Comment: Also worth nothing that there is ErrorT in mtl, and that also implements MonadPlus, meaning that the code above would work almost unchanged in the Error monad.  (The change is that the "Left" part of ErrorT needs a type signature, since "mzero" isn't quite specific enough.)

Comment: @jrockway: And the left type would need an `Error` instance, which is a bit unconvenient because `MaybeT` is actually isomorphic to something like `ErrorT ()`, but this isn't allowed since there is no `instance Error ()`. Better to use `EitherT`, but this also requires an additional package.

Answer (score 17):

You don't exactly say how you want to combine `IO` and `Maybe`, but I assume you have many functions that return `IO (Maybe a)` that you want to combine easily. Basically you want to treat `IO (Maybe a)` as a separate type with it's own `Monad` instance:

```
newtype IOMaybe a = IOM (IO (Maybe a))

-- "unpack" a value of the new type
runIOMaybe :: IOMaybe a -> IO (Maybe a)
runIOMaybe (IOM a) = a

instance Monad IOMaybe where
   -- bind operator
   (IOM ioa) >>= f = IOM $ do
      a <- ioa
      case a of
         Nothing -> return Nothing
         Just v  -> runIOMaybe (f v)

   -- return
   return a = IOM (return (Just a))

-- maybe also some convenience functions
returnIO :: IO a -> IOMaybe a
returnIO ioa = IOM $ do
   v <- ioa
   return (Just v)

returnMaybe :: Maybe a -> IOMaybe a
returnMaybe ma = IOM (return ma)
```

With this you can use the `do`-Notation to combine functions that return `IO (Maybe a)`, `IO a` or `Maybe a`:

```
f1 :: Int -> IO (Maybe Int)
f1 0 = return Nothing
f1 a = return (Just a)

main = runIOMaybe $ do
   returnIO $ putStrLn "Hello"
   a <- returnMaybe $ Just 2
   IOM $ f1 a
   return ()
```

Generally something that combines and modifies monads like this is called a [monad transformer](http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monad_Transformers_Explained), and GHC comes with a [package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl/) that includes monad transformers for common cases. If there is something in this monad transformer library that fits your scenario depends on how exactly you want to combine Maybe and IO.

Comment: If you weren't aware, you can automatically create the `runIOMaybe` by instead declaring `newtype IOMaybe a = IOM { runIOMaybe :: IO (Maybe a) }`

Answer (score 0):

In what sense do you want to combine the monads?

```
f :: Int -> IO (Maybe Int)
f x = do
    putStrLn "Hello world!"
    return $ if x == 0 then Nothing else Just x
```

Can be evaluated to:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( maybe-io.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> f 0
Hello world!
Nothing
*Main> f 3
Hello world!
Just 3
```

Comment: You are not composing computations over Maybe, and hence the fact that Maybe is a monad is irrelevant.